# Finding the subarray with the Maximum sum in the given ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, dynamic-programming, sub-array

The problem description:

Given an `ArrayList` of `Integers`. Find a **subarray** with the ***maximum sum*** of any potential subarray within the `ArrayList`.

A **subarray** a is a combination of consecutive numbers.

The subarray can be of any length `n`, where the size of `n >= 0`.

*Example*

**Input:**

```
[-1, 10, -11, -1, 17, 0, 0, 9, 20, 7, -8, -6, -18]
```

**Solution**

```
[17, 0, 0, 9, 20, 0, 7]
```

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
public class MaxSubArray {

    public ArrayList<Integer> solution(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        int maxSubArrSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int greatest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int smallest = 0;
        int start;
        int end;
        ArrayList<Integer> maxSubArr;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList();

        try {
            for (int left = 0; left < nums.size(); left++) {
                int runningSum = 0;
                for (int right = left; right < nums.size(); right++) {
                    runningSum += nums.get(right);
                    if (runningSum >= maxSubArrSum) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                        maxSubArrSum = runningSum;
                        start = left;
                        end = right;
                        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                            temp.add(nums.get(i));
                        }
                        lists.add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
                if (lists.get(i).size() < greatest) {
                    greatest = lists.get(i).size();
                    smallest = i;
                }
            }
            maxSubArr = lists.get(smallest);
            return maxSubArr;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return nums;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through the `nums` `ArrayList` and figuring out the *first* and *last* indexes of the **subarrays** with the *maximum sum* and putting them in a list of `ArrayList`s.

After that, I am trying to figure out which of the **subarrays** has the *smallest size* and returning it.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not really using your variable `maxSubArraySum`. You can easily delete it and inline the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more concise solution

```
private List<Integer> solution(List<Integer> nums) {
    int biggestSumSoFar = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    List<Integer> biggestSubListSoFar = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int left = 0; left < nums.size(); ++left) {
        for (int right = left + 1; right < nums.size(); ++right) {
            List<Integer> currentSubList = subListSum(nums, left, right);
            int currentSum = sum(currentSubList);
            if (currentSum > biggestSumSoFar) {
                biggestSumSoFar = currentSum;
                biggestSubListSoFar = currentSubList;
            }
        }
    }
    return biggestSubListSoFar;
}

private List<Integer> subListSum(final List<Integer> nums, final int left, final int right)
{
    final List<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++)
    {
        sublist.add(nums.get(i));
    }
    return sublist;
}

private int sum(List<Integer> arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int a : arr){
        sum += a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the best answer for my use. I made a few adjustments and I was able to reach a solution.

Comment: @this.R.A Accepting the answer your responsibility, and you are free to accept any answer. But keep in mind that although this solution is very close to your initial, it *isn't the best way to approach this problem* because it'll will run in a **quadratic time O(n^2)**. And this problem can be solved in a **linear time**. It is worth to point that out for the benefit of *future readers* of that will deal with a similar task.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a third inner for-loop can make the task probably easier. Just think about how you would do it with a pen and paper. Imagine you have an array of 6 elements with indices from `0` to `5`, then all possible subarrays would have the following start and end indices (strat inclusive, end exclusive)

```
0 - 1     1 - 2     2 - 3     3 - 4     4 - 5
0 - 2     1 - 3     2 - 4     3 - 5   
0 - 3     1 - 4     2 - 5   
0 - 4     1 - 5   
0 - 5
```

Having the above all you need is to calculate the subsum and store the relevant start and end indices

```
public List<Integer> solution(List<Integer> nums) {
    int maxSubArrSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int start = 0;
    int end   = 0;
    for (int left = 0; left < nums.size(); left++){
        for (int right = left+1; right < nums.size(); right++){
            int subSum = 0;
            for (int k = left; k < right; k++){
                subSum += nums.get(k);
            }
            if (subSum > maxSubArrSum){
                maxSubArrSum = subSum;                    
                start = left;
                end   = right;
            }
        }
    }
    return nums.subList(start,end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quiet close with your approach.
There are two problems with the last part:

1. `int greatest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` should be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead.
2. You check for the size of a subarray but you have to check for the sum of the subarray.

if you change the last part to:

```
int greatest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    if (sum(lists.get(i)) > greatest) {
        greatest = lists.get(i).size();
        smallest = i;
    }
}
```

by utilizing

```
public static int sum(List<Integer> arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int a : arr){
        sum += a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

it yields the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to approach this task with a **brute-force** algorithm, which in the worse case scenario will have the **O(n^2)** both time and space complexity.

It could be done with a *linear* (i.e. **O(n)**) both time and space complexity, without *nested loops*.

With this approach, first, we need to find the **maximum possible sum** of the subarray by using the [**Kadane's algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm).

And then perform the iteration with over the *source list* in a single loop tracking the ***current sum***. When it becomes equal to the *maximum sum* it would mean the target subarray of consecutive elements was found.

Variables `start` and `end` denote the *starting* and *ending* indices of the resulting *subarray*.

Method `subList()` creates a *view* over the source list and every modification of the *view* will be reflected in the source and vice versa. Hence, as a precaution it's being wrapped with with a new instance of `ArrayList`.

```
public static List<Integer> solution(List<Integer> nums) {
    if (nums.size() == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    final int maxSum = getMaxSum(nums); // getting max sum by using Kadane's algorithm
    int curSum = nums.get(0);

    int start = 0; // beginning of the resulting subarray
    int end = 0; // end of the resulting subarray exclusive

    for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (curSum == maxSum) {
            end = i;
            break; // maximus sub-array was found
        }

        if (nums.get(i) > curSum + nums.get(i)) {
            start = i;             // setting start to current index
            curSum = nums.get(i);  // assigning the current element the sum
        } else {
            curSum += nums.get(i); // adding the current element to the sum
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(nums.subList(start, end));
}
```

***Kadane's** algorithm implementation*.

The overall idea is to maintain two variables denoting the *global* and a *local* maximum. There are to ways in which the *local maximum* changes with each iteration, we either

- adding the current element to the *local maximum*;
- or assigning the current element's value to the *local maximum*.

At the end of every iteration, the *global maximum* is being compared with a *local maximum* and adjusted if needed.

```
public static int getMaxSum(List<Integer> nums) {
    int maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int curSum = nums.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        curSum = Math.max(nums.get(i), curSum + nums.get(i));
        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, curSum);
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> source = List.of(-1, 10, -11, -1, 17, 0, 0, 9, 20, 7, -8, -6, -18);
    System.out.println(solution(source));
}
```

**output**

```
[17, 0, 0, 9, 20, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of [Kadane's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) to find the largest sum of contiguous elements in a list. It is adapted from a solution given in Python and works in a single pass.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(-1, 10, -11, -1, 17, 0, 0, 9, 20, 7, -8, -6, -18);
List<Integer> subList = maxSubArray(list); 
System.out.println(subList);
```

prints

```
[17, 0, 0, 9, 20, 7]

public static List<Integer> maxSubArray(List<Integer> list) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int sum = max;
    int end = 0;
    int cstart = 0, start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int val = list.get(i);
        if (sum <= 0) {
            sum = val;
            cstart = i;
        } else {
            sum += val;
        }
        if (sum > max) {
              max = sum;
              start = cstart;
              end = i;              
        }
    }
    return list.subList(start,end+1); 
}
```